# Not able to set the value in a variable in React

Tags: reactjs, react-props

In my reactjs application, I am trying to set the value to variable data but it is not getting assigned. It should be assigned from nextProps.samples which contains values and I am able to log in my browser console, those values.

Here is piece of code:

```
export default class GeofencingSamplesDL extends React.Component {
  // eslint-disable-line react/prefer-stateless-function

  state = {
    data: []
  };

  componentWillReceiveProps = nextProps => {
    let data = [];

    if (this.props.samples !== nextProps.samples) {

      nextProps.samples.forEach(sample => {
        data.push({
          Date: sample.timestamp,
          Semelle: sample.macAddress,
          Gateway: sample.deviceID,
          Pas: sample.steps,
          RSSI: sample.rssi,
          RawSteps: sample.rawSteps
        });        

        // Here values are visible as I print in console
        console.log("Sample " + JSON.stringify(sample));        



      });

      // Here values are not getting set
      this.setState({ data });      
    }

  };
```

Any way out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you logging the state ?

Comment: What you are trying to do is actually an anti-pattern. Also how do you know the state is not updated? `setState` might be async. So you'll need to pass a callback `this.setState({data}, () => {/* updated state here*/}); /* old state here*/`

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops "If you used componentWillReceiveProps for re-computing some data only when a prop changes, use a memoization helper instead."

Comment: Basically, my objective is to get the data and put it on CsvDownloader so that I can download it. Here is code: <CsvDownloader datas={this.state.data} filename={data-${this.props.from}-${this.props.to}-${ this.props.day }} >

Comment: Here everytime csv downloads blank file

Comment: @Yury Tarabanko:  I am directly fetching the value on button click for downloading it to csv.  
 <CsvDownloader datas={this.state.data} filename={data-${this.props.from}-${this.props.to}-${ this.props.day }} >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setState is async/sync based on how you invoke it. 
The values are set but you cannot see it yet. Try logging the data in the render. 
Or try this 
`this.setState({ data }, () => console.log(this.state.data))`;

Using this componentWillReceiveProps method often leads to bugs and inconsistencies.
more here https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops

Comment: Basically, my objective is to get the data and put it on CsvDownloader so that I can download it. Here is code:  <CsvDownloader
              datas={this.state.data}
              filename={`data-${this.props.from}-${this.props.to}-${
                this.props.day
                }`}
            >

Comment: Here everytime csv downloads blank file

Comment: Can you please post the full code here or you can create a jsfiddle or codepen. It will easy for us to debug what is going on there.

Comment: Here is link for the specific js file: https://github.com/arindam-b/DNSissue/blob/master/index.js

Comment: You can just use map to convert you samples instead of relying on setState and componentWillRecieveProps. I got it working here https://jsfiddle.net/6vraf0Lz/2/

Answer (score 0):

a) `componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated/consider unsafe in the latest release of React. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops. This is probably the reason for your bug.

b) `getDerivedStateFromProps` is the preferred lifecycle method for this purpose https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

c) alternatively you can refactor this component as a functional component and use React hooks

Comment: Thanks. But I am not using latest version, it is in prod since 1 year. So not expecting componentWillReceiveProps as deprecated.